# Windows 10 cut and paste: do not copy already existing files to the destination, but still removing them in original folder

Tags: windows, cut-and-paste

Due to some connection issues, some of my files from my phone are pasted to my computer but they were not removed from the original folder. I would like to repeat the cut/paste but without recopying the files that are already in the destination (my computer), while removing them from the original (my phone).

Is it possible to do this with Windows "natively" or with some kind of utility software?

Comment: *"Due to some connection issues..."* - If there were connections issues, it might be best to simply recopy all the files, as some files may have been transferred but could contain errors.

Answer (score 0):

No. Because it is normally quite difficult or time-consuming to determine what "some" means, and it is easy to make an error here. So it is better to ensure the source and (truly assured of the source) delete the target and restart the copy. This is the best way (and yes, I have walked in your shoes).